# Spring MVC Support for mobile devices and standard browser

Tags: spring, rest, jsp, model-view-controller

I am designing a dashboard application using Spring MVC Restful APIs. One of the requirements is to support mobile devices and standard browser.

Please let me know if I can implement this in Presentation layer (JSP), if yes, how can we achieve it?

Comment: by "support mobile devices" do you mean with an android/ios app or by connecting with the browser from a mobile device?

Comment: Hi Spalla Diago, it's connecting with the browser from a mobile device.

Comment: From a mobile device there is no need for extra configuration as you can connect to the web app as you would do from any other browser, you only need to implement a responsive graphic in order to display the page properly without scrolling bar or other annoying glitch. In presentation layer, if you are using JSPs, you can use framework like Bootstrap if you don't need anything special but responsive code.

Comment: Thanks Spalla Diego for your response. This info is useful to me.